# xlwt limiting the number of rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwt

I got the error below when I run the python tool to create an xls file by reading an xml file. How do I fix it?

```
ValueError: row index (65536) not an int in range(65536)
File "D:\Zipfiles\Script_try.py", line 82, in _execute_test
    self.parser = parser()
  File "D:\Zipfiles\Script_try.py", line 216, in __init__
    self._xml_parser()
  File "D:\Zipfiles\Script_try.py", line 306, in _xml_parser
    sheet1.write(row,1,[test_x.attrib['name']],centr)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1078, in row
    self.__rows[indx] = self.Row(indx, self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise ValueError("row index (%r) not an int in range(65536)" % rowx)
ValueError: row index (65536) not an int in range(65536)
```

Answer (score 9):

The maximum number of rows in .xls file is 65536. Use .xlsx instead or another format that allows more rows.

Answer (score 8):

It is a bit unfair to say that xlwt is limiting this. The limit is imposed by Excel in the XLS format.

You could use [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org) instead which supports the new Excel XLSX limits of 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. You can try with [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) instead of xlwt. Good luck!